# Can I multiply every value in a column by a certain number in one database action?

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have a Rails block that multiplies every value in a column by 1.1. Is there a way to condense this into only one or a few database actions, as opposed to one for every row?

```
def multiply
  Item.all.each do |item|
    item.value = item.value * 1.1
    item.save
  end
end
```

My Item table is like 1000 rows long, so I'm worried this might be an undue strain on my server.

Comment: I'd do it using plain sql if possible, it's faster than ruby code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done in Rails with `update_all` and a bit `SQL`:

```
Item.update_all('value = value * 1.1')
```

Another option is pure `SQL` (for example in the database console):

```
UPDATE items SET value = value * 1.1;
```

Or in batches, what does not stress the database that much, but will certainly take much longer:

```
Items.find_each { |item| item.update_attribute(:value, item.value * 1.1) }
```

---

Databases were build to handle millions of rows and thousands of reading and writing operations per second. From that point of view, a table with 1000 rows is tiny and updating all rows at once is not a problem for a database at all. The database does not care if there is one big or thousands of small updates.

BUT the application might have problems. There are implications to consider when you have a bigger database and many users.

Imagine you have a table with millions of rows.

While updating all rows at once might be faster from the database's point of view than updating the rows in batches (or even one by one). But updating all rows at once might lock the whole table during that operation or at least slows down the database's response time. Read operation on that table will be very slow and users will have a bad experience.

Whereas an update in batches (or every single line) will take much longer, but the application would not be slowed down. Happy users...!